# Memory comparison, which is faster?

Tags: c++, comparison

I have a 3D vector class. The private variables are defined:

```
union {
    struct {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
    };
    double data[3];
};
```

In implementing operator==, which is faster?

```
return this->x == v.x && this->y == v.y && this->z == v.z;
```

OR

```
return memcmp(this->data, v.data) == 0;
```

Comment: I used the union so I can just pass `data` to 3rd party APIs that require a `double*`.

Comment: @Stephen - directly memcmp-ing a structure can be risky.  If the compiler puts in padding, the structures may be different even though all the fields are the same.

Comment: @R Samuel : Thanks, good point.  _comment withdrawn._ :)

Comment: Here's another thing to consider about performance, especially considering 3D graphics:  Chances are, if you are asking about performance, you still have a lot to learn before you'll be truly *efficient*.  There is such an astounding amount of knowledge required in that space, that you're probably better off just making everything clean and functional until you have a 100% working program.  Then you can try tweaking and optimization, delving into assembler, clock-tick measurements, and all sorts of fun compiler flags!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately the two aren't equivalent.  (Specifically NaNs and signed zeros don't use bitwise comparison inside the FPU).

So you should make your choice based on correctness, not speed.

Comment: Right, I just completely forgot about that. Rookie mistake I suppose.

Comment: @Duracell: The rookie mistake is worrying about performance over good code. :) Performance is your last concern.

Comment: @GMan: You could say that, but I'd completely overlooked the fact that memcmp wouldn't work. Without that, I'd assumed my code was good and could therefore look at speed.

Comment: OK @Ben Voigt, with that out of the way, what if the vectors just used ints? And I know all about the "Don't prematurely optimize!!!!1" argument. I'm just interested to know.

Comment: ints use bitwise comparison.  Actually, using bitwise comparison on doubles is not necessarily a bad thing, *if you don't want IEEE handling of NaN values*.  For example, using IEEE comparisons can result in the following: `bool func(vector a) { vector b = a; return b == a; }` returning `false` (in the case of quiet NaNs) or even crashing (in the case of signalling NaNs).

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case.