# C array comparison

Tags: c, arrays, unit-testing, memcmp

Is the defacto method for comparing arrays (in C) to use `memcmp` from `string.h`?

I want to compare arrays of ints and doubles in my unit tests

I am unsure whether to use  something like:

```
double a[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
double b[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
size_t n = 3;
if (! memcmp(a, b, n * sizeof(double)))
    /* arrays equal */
```

or to write a bespoke `is_array_equal(a, b, n)` type function?

Comment: I think you mean memcmp. memset would overwrite the first array.

Comment: IIRC `memset` will change (_set_) values in the array so that's not usefull for only _comparing_ arrays.

Comment: yes, memcmp that is what i meant - is this considered good practice?

Comment: @Hiett: depends on what you want. `memcmp` compares byte-for-byte, which may not be what you want (esp. with floating-point values).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`memcmp` would do an *exact* comparison, which is seldom a good idea for floats, and would not follow the rule that NaN != NaN. For sorting, that's fine, but for other purposes, you might to do an approximate comparison such as:

```
bool dbl_array_eq(double const *x, double const *y, size_t n, double eps)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (fabs(x[i] - y[i]) > eps)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i see - i've written a similar function but was concerned that it was 'overkill' and I should maybe trying to use more generic library functions, not reinventing the wheel and all that. I think I will stick with your recommendation

Comment: whats the bool datatype? is that not a C++ thing?

Comment: @Hiett: since C99, `bool` is part of C. It's in `<stdbool.h>` and comes with macros `true` and `false`. If you're on MSVC, you may not have `stdbool.h` since that compiler only supports C89.

Comment: in <stdbool.h> am I right in thinking true and false are #defines of 1 and 0, e.g. they can be used interchangeably? Thinking about how to best integrate into my existing code

Comment: @Hiett: yes, you can assume those values for `true` and `false`.

Comment: You should change it in `if(!((fabs(x[i] - y[i]) <= eps))`, so you can handle a `NaN`. In your code, a NaN value will never return a `false`

Answer (score 6):

Using `memcmp` is not generally a good idea. Let's start with the more complex and work down from there.

---

Though you mentioned `int` and `double`, I first want to concentrate on `memcmp` as a general solution, such as to compare arrays of type:

```
struct {
    char c;
    // 1
    int i;
    // 2
}
```

The main problem there is that implementations are free to add padding to structures at locations 1 and 2, making a bytewise comparison potentially false even though the important bits match perfectly.

---

Now down to doubles. You might think this was better as there's no padding there. However there are other problems.

The first is the treatment of `NaN` values. IEEE754 goes out of its way to ensure that `NaN` is not equal to any other value, including itself. For example, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    double d1 = 0.0 / 0.0, d2 = d1;

    if (d1 == d2)
        puts ("Okay");
    else
        puts ("Bad");

    if (memcmp (&d1, &d2, sizeof(double)) == 0)
        puts ("Okay");
    else puts
        ("Bad");

    return 0;
}
```

will output

```
Bad
Okay
```

illustrating the difference.

The second is the treatment of plus and minus zero. These should be considered equal for the purposes of comparison but, as the bit patterns are different, `memcmp` will say they are different.

Changing the declaration/initialisation of `d1` and `d2` in the above code to:

```
 double d1 = 0.0, d2 = -d1;
```

will make this clear.

---

So, if structures and doubles are problematic, surely integers are okay. After all, they're always two's complement, yes?

No, actually they're not. ISO mandates one of three encoding schemes for signed integers and the other two (ones' complements and sign/magnitude) suffer from a similar problem as doubles, that fact that both plus and minus zero exist.

So, while they should possibly be considered equal, again the bit patterns are different.

Even for *unsigned* integers, you have a problem (it's also a problem for signed values as well). ISO states that these representations can have value bits and padding bits, and that the values of the padding bits are unspecified.

So, even for what may seem the simplest case, `memcmp` can be a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `memset` with `memcmp` in your code, and it works.

In your case (as the size both arrays arrays are identical and known during compilation) you can even do:

```
memcmp(a, b, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is `memcmp`, **not** `memset`. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090038/memory-comparison-which-is-faster) for why it might not be a good idea to `memcmp` an array of doubles though.

Answer (score 2):

memcmp compares two blocks of memory for number of size given

memset is used to initialise buffer with a value for size given

buffers can be compared without using memcmp in following way. same can be changed for different datatypes.

```
int8_t array_1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
int8_t array_2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

uint8_t i;
uint8_t compare_result = 1;

for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(array_1)/sizeof(int8_t); i++)
{
 if (array_1[i] != array_2[i])
  {
   compare_result = 0;
   break;
  }
}
```